Are there any authority references showing how to track TSO/CSO?
The airlines that I worked for and I worked with has been tracking TSO value as same as TSN until the unit has been overhauled.
As far as I know this is the common practice and there should be some documentation,I couldn’t find so far. Do you guys know any reference for this or similar showing how to track serialised parts? Thanks a lot.
